Auth0: _auth0 variable wasn't initialised
this is a snippet from my code. For some reason, LINE A throws an error saying Invalid argument(s): Auth0Client has not been initialized. I have tried a couple of approaches (wrapping it into a constructor, local initialisation, etc.) but I can't get it to work. It's strange because the environment variables exist, the lines with the initialisation are also getting executed. By the way, these secrets work just fine in an example repository that Auth0 provided, so it has surely got something to do my code.

class AuthState extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Auth0 _auth0 = Auth0(dotenv.env["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]!, dotenv.env["AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"]!);
  final Auth0Web _auth0Web = Auth0Web(dotenv.env["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]!, dotenv.env["AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"]!);
  final String _appScheme = defaultAppScheme;
  
  Credentials? _credentials;
  Future<void> login() async {
   

    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
LINE A        await _auth0Web.loginWithRedirect(redirectUrl: dotenv.env["WEB_DOMAIN"]);
        _credentials = await _auth0Web.credentials();
      } else {
        _credentials = await _auth0.webAuthentication(scheme: _appScheme).login();
      }
      
    } 
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    
  }

}


Complete code:
import 'package:app/src/constants/text.dart';
import 'package:app/src/utils/services/userAndAccess.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:auth0_flutter/auth0_flutter.dart';
import 'package:auth0_flutter/auth0_flutter_web.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

import 'package:app/src/constants/urls.dart';


const defaultAppScheme = "melontechapp";


/// A class to encapsulate the Auth0 authentication code.
/// Used to broadcast the user to other widgets.
/// 
/// States can be read by using `context.watch<AuthState>()`.
class AuthState extends ChangeNotifier {
    late Auth0 _auth0;
  late Auth0Web _auth0Web;

  

 AuthState(){
_auth0 = Auth0(dotenv.env["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]!, dotenv.env["AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"]!);
 _auth0Web = Auth0Web(dotenv.env["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]!, dotenv.env["AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"]!);
 }
 
  final String _appScheme = defaultAppScheme;
  
  Credentials? _credentials;

  bool _loading = false;
  String? _errorMessage;

  /// Returns App Scheme being used by Auth0
  String? get appScheme => _appScheme;

  /// Returns current logged in user (or `null` if no one is logged in).
  UserProfile? get user => _credentials?.user;

  /// Returns whether the app is currently in a loading state.
  bool get loading => _loading;

  /// Returns current Auth0 error message (or `null` if there is no error).
  String? get error => _errorMessage;

  /// Returns `true` if there is an Auth0 error.
  bool get isError => _errorMessage != null;

  /// Puts the app into a loading state.
  void startLoading() {
    _loading = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Stops the app from being in a loading state.
  void stopLoading() {
    _loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> checkLoggedIn() async {
    _loading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final isLoggedIn;
    if (kIsWeb) {
      isLoggedIn = await _auth0Web.hasValidCredentials();
    } else {
      isLoggedIn = await _auth0.credentialsManager.hasValidCredentials();
    }

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        _credentials = await _auth0Web.credentials();
      } else {
        _credentials = await _auth0.credentialsManager.credentials();
      }
    } else {
      _credentials = null;
    }

    _loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return isLoggedIn;
  }

  /// Performs Auth0 login. Opens a popup in the browser, requesting user to input details, before returning to app.
  Future<void> login() async {
    _loading = true;
    _errorMessage = null;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        await _auth0Web.loginWithRedirect(redirectUrl: dotenv.env["WEB_DOMAIN"]);
        _credentials = await _auth0Web.credentials();
      } else {
        _credentials = await _auth0.webAuthentication(scheme: _appScheme).login();
      }
      
      if (_credentials != null) {
        int status = await createAccount(_credentials!.user.sub, {
          uAANameParam: _credentials!.user.name ?? "",
          uAAEmailParam: _credentials!.user.email ?? "",
        });

        if (status != 201) {
          if (status == 200) {
            _errorMessage = loginAccountExistsError;
          } else {
            _errorMessage = loginServerError;
          }
          logout();
        }
      } else { 
        _errorMessage = loginServerError;
      }

    } 
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    // on WebException {
    //   _errorMessage = loginIncompleteError;
    // } on WebAuthenticationException {
    //   _errorMessage = loginIncompleteError;
    // } on Exception catch (e, s) {
    //   debugPrint('login error: $e - stack: \n$s');
    //   // _errorMessage = e.toString();
    //   _errorMessage = loginServerError;

    // } finally {
    //   _loading = false;
    //   notifyListeners();
    // }
  }

  /// Performs Auth0 logout. Opens a popup in the browser before returning to app.
  Future<void> logout() async {
    _loading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        await _auth0Web.logout(returnToUrl: dotenv.env["WEB_DOMAIN"]);
      } else {
        await _auth0.webAuthentication(scheme: _appScheme).logout();
      }
      _credentials = null;

    } on WebException {
      _errorMessage = logoutError;
    } on WebAuthenticationException {
      _errorMessage = logoutError;
    } on Exception catch (e, s) {
      debugPrint('login error: $e - stack: $s');
      _errorMessage = logoutError;
      // _errorMessage = e.toString();

    } finally {
      _loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}


This is one way to do it, it will ensure that auth0 and auth0web will be initialize when you provide AuthState:
class AuthState extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Auth0 auth0;
  final Auth0Web auth0Web;

  AuthState({
    required this.auth0,
    required this.auth0Web,
  });

  final String _appScheme = defaultAppScheme;

  Credentials? _credentials;

  bool _loading = false;
  String? _errorMessage;

  /// Returns App Scheme being used by Auth0
  String? get appScheme => _appScheme;

  /// Returns current logged in user (or `null` if no one is logged in).
  UserProfile? get user => _credentials?.user;

  /// Returns whether the app is currently in a loading state.
  bool get loading => _loading;

  /// Returns current Auth0 error message (or `null` if there is no error).
  String? get error => _errorMessage;

  /// Returns `true` if there is an Auth0 error.
  bool get isError => _errorMessage != null;

  /// Puts the app into a loading state.
  void startLoading() {
    _loading = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Stops the app from being in a loading state.
  void stopLoading() {
    _loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> checkLoggedIn() async {
    _loading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final isLoggedIn;
    if (kIsWeb) {
      isLoggedIn = await auth0Web.hasValidCredentials();
    } else {
      isLoggedIn = await auth0.credentialsManager.hasValidCredentials();
    }

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        _credentials = await auth0Web.credentials();
      } else {
        _credentials = await auth0.credentialsManager.credentials();
      }
    } else {
      _credentials = null;
    }

    _loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return isLoggedIn;
  }

  Future<void> login() async {
    _loading = true;
    _errorMessage = null;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        await auth0Web.loginWithRedirect(
            redirectUrl: dotenv.env["WEB_DOMAIN"]);
        _credentials = await auth0Web.credentials();
      } else {
        _credentials =
            await auth0.webAuthentication(scheme: _appScheme).login();
      }

      if (_credentials != null) {
        print("200");
      } else {
        print("500");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    _loading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        await auth0Web.logout(returnToUrl: dotenv.env["WEB_DOMAIN"]);
      } else {
        await auth0.webAuthentication(scheme: _appScheme).logout();
      }
      _credentials = null;
    } on WebException {
      print("WebException");
    } on WebAuthenticationException {
      print("WebAuthenticationException");
    } on Exception catch (e, s) {
      print("Exception");
      // _errorMessage = e.toString();
    } finally {
      _loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}


I tried this, but it didn't work either. I declared them as late variables and then initialised them inside the method constructor.

Would you please show more code content?

I've put the entire code into the description now. I know it is not the most efficient way, but I'm desperate to fix it having spent 6+ hours on it.

I did consider that as well, especially cause the example repo provided by auth0 used a stateful widget. I'm working on legacy code, so there's a lot of moving pieces in the notifyListeners() bit, which is why I'm worried it might break the app.

I will show an example using your approach.\

I am going to give it a go
